# Books on turbulent compressible fluid (gas) in heated channel

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

It's been a while I got my hands dirty with simulation of hydrodynamics and it was mostly incompressible and laminar. Now, I need to model turbulent flow in channel with additional external heating going on and I would like to refresh basic theory of compressible flows.

I would like deep and detailed theoretical treatment of compressible fluids, to refresh the fundamentals and to help me figure out how to couple turbulent gas flow with heating (of boundaries of channel).

Currently on my bookshelf lonely sits Lamb's hydrodynamics (which as far as I remember doesn't deal with compressible fluids).

I would very much appreciate all kinds of responses and suggestions.

Comment: For questions on numerical methods, the site scicomp.stackexchange.com is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you, didn't know such thing existed. Should I edit the post? I still need some reference more modern than Lamb (with all due respect to this venerable book I used as a student) and more focused on compressible fluids.

Comment: Splitting the numerical question off to scicomp and leaving the theoretical reference request here seems reasonable to me.